Can atomic.Value store a zero interface{}?
package atomicvalue

import "sync/atomic"

type AtomicValue[T any] struct {
    v atomic.Value
}

func (av *AtomicValue[T]) Load() T {
    if v := av.v.Load(); v != nil {
        return v.(T)
    } else {
        var v T
        return v
    }
}

func (av *AtomicValue[T]) Store(value T) {
    av.v.Store(value)
}

func (av *AtomicValue[T]) CompareAndSwap(old, new T) bool {
    return av.v.CompareAndSwap(old, new)
}

func (av *AtomicValue[T]) Swap(new T) (old T) {
    old = av.Load()
    av.Store(new)
    return old
}

I wrap the atomic.Value to a generic type.
I handled the zero value in Load() function, but I can't store nil.
type MyInterface interface{
    One()
    Two()
    Three()
}

var value atomicvalue.AtomicValue[MyInterface]
bar:=&MyStruct{} // MyStruct implements MyInterface
value.store(bar) // ok
value.store(nil) // panic there

When I store a nil, there will be a panic:
panic: sync/atomic: store of nil value into Value


According to the docs:

A Value provides an atomic load and store of a consistently typed value.

So this works:
    v := atomic.Value{}
    var x *int
    v.Store(x)

But this doesn't, nor would any other nil interface value, because the actual type of the value is not consistent:
    v := atomic.Value{}
    var x any
    v.Store(x)


Load() returns the value set by the most recent Store. It returns nil if there has been no call to Store for this Value. so is there no way to reset/delete/clear the atomic.Value so that Load() can return nil again after store a value?

You can do that with a pointer to a value.
